# found [nvarchar2 (Types#OTHER)], but expecting [varchar2(255 char) (Types#VARCHAR)]

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle12c

I am using Oracle database 12c, Hibernate 5. 
DDL

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHORITIES 
(
  AUTHORITY NVARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL 
, USERNAME NVARCHAR2(64) 
, CONSTRAINT AUTHORITIES_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    AUTHORITY 
  )
  USING INDEX 
  (
      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX AUTHORITIES_PK ON AUTHORITIES (AUTHORITY ASC) 
      LOGGING 
      TABLESPACE USERS 
      PCTFREE 10 
      INITRANS 2 
      STORAGE 
      ( 
        INITIAL 65536 
        NEXT 1048576 
        MINEXTENTS 1 
        MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
        BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
      ) 
      NOPARALLEL 
  )
  ENABLE 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE USERS 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS 
NO INMEMORY 
NOPARALLEL;
```

I have entity

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;    
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Role entity.
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORITIES")
public class Authorities {    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "AUTHORITY")
    private String authority;    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME")
    private User user;

    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }    
    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }    
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }    
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }    
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in com.donhuvy.config.AppConfig:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: 
Schema-validation: 
wrong column type encountered in column [AUTHORITY] in table [AUTHORITIES]; found [nvarchar2 (Types#OTHER)], but expecting [varchar2(255 char) (Types#VARCHAR)]
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I am not a Java pro. But a little googling gave me this. See if this helps. https://cedar715.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-wrong-column-type-found-char-expected-varchar2255/

Comment: I did like this, it not work

Comment: By not working, do you mean that it gave the same error again or did it give you a different error? Also please share what was changed in your code.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a little bit old but I just run into the same problem and resolved it.
Just extend your annotation like this:

```
(...)
@Column(name = "AUTHORITY", columnDefinition = "varchar2")
private String authority; 
(...)
```